# How to get row view data in the listview

Tags: android, android-layout

this example: http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html  .There are 3 textview ids at custom_row_view.xml. There are 3 row data inside one position listitem when using onListItemClick. how to extract these data? how to use the id? Anyway to get row view data in the list view when the list item is clicked
[protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter `View v` itself is the row view. You can get the attached data by calling `v.getTag()`. Should set it earlier in getView of adapter using `v.setTag(Object)`

Comment: this example: http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html. There are 3 textview ids at custom_row_view.xml.  There are 3 row data inside one position listitem when using onListItemClick. how to extract these data? how to use the id?

Comment: You can use `findviewbyId` and get the tags attached to the views.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the kind of data. For example id does contain the _id from a database table row that was set with one of the CursorAdapters. Usually this is the PK of that database table row.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.getAdapter().getItemAt(position)
```

gets you the object bound to the view V

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend you not to get data from the view, instead ***use the ArrayList you have used to set data to the Adapter of the ListView***.

In the example which you have pointed out, you are using an ArrayList of HashMap. So for an example..

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // arrayList is the variable which you have used as a list in your SimpleAdapter
        hashMap = arrayList.get((int)id); // you need to typecast 'id' from long to int
        value = hashMap.get(KEY);
    }
});
```